# How to Make an Item Flow with the Application Bar

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, animation, windows-phone-8

I would like to hover some items above the application bar, so it looks like they are just stacked on top of the appbar. I need to have these move with the app bar accordingly as a user taps the ellipses of the appbar to go to the menu item options, and then follow the app bar back to its original position when the user taps out.

Something like the following is what I'd like to accomplish

[image]

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListBox x:Name="ImageBar"
            Grid.Row="1" Background="Silver"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}"                     
            SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=ContentPivot, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <customcontrols:SplitPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBoxItem>
                            <Image Source="/Assets/add.png"/>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <Image Source="/Assets/edit.png"/>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <Image Source="/Assets/close.png"/>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <Image Source="/Assets/delete.png"/>
            </ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>

        <controls:Pivot x:Name="ContentPivot"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Margin="0,-12,0,0">
            <controls:PivotItem>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="add" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <RichTextBox Margin="0,12,0,0">
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."/>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </RichTextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </controls:PivotItem>
            <controls:PivotItem>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="edit" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <RichTextBox Margin="0,12,0,0">
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text="Sed bibendum vehicula quam."/>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </RichTextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </controls:PivotItem>
            <controls:PivotItem>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="close" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <RichTextBox Margin="0,12,0,0">
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text="Integer eget molestie lacus."/>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </RichTextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </controls:PivotItem>
            <controls:PivotItem>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="delete" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <RichTextBox Margin="0,12,0,0">
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text="Phasellus molestie volutpat ante pulvinar convallis."/>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </RichTextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </controls:PivotItem>
        </controls:Pivot>
    </Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void BuildApplicationBar()
    {
        ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
        ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Minimized;

        ApplicationBarMenuItem menuItem1 = new ApplicationBarMenuItem();
        menuItem1.Text = "menu item 1";
        menuItem1.Click += menuItem1_Click;

        ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(menuItem1);
    }

    private void menuItem1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Menu item 1 works!");
    }
```

The themeing and all that I'm not worried about. I'd just like to get the functionality down. basically when the user taps the ellipse, I'd like the `ImageBar` to be able to rise and fall like it is on top of the application bar. How might I do something like this? Also, I'd like to be able to support portrait and landscape, as well as more than 1 menu item. Is there a way to do this automatically? If not, how might I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the ApplicationBar.StateChanged event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbar.statechanged(v=vs.105).aspx

From your event handler check the event args IsMenuVisible property and make your layout adjustments accordingly.

```
public MainPage()
{
    ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
    ApplicationBar.StateChanged += ApplicationBar_StateChanged;
}

void ApplicationBar_StateChanged(object sender, ApplicationBarStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsMenuVisible)
    {
        // Move Image Up
    }
    else
    {
        // Move Image Down
    }
}
```

Regarding your other questions. Yes you can support portrait/landscape or both. In your XAML look for the phone:PhoneApplicationPage SupportedOrientations property, it will default to "Portrait" in a new project. Just change it to PortraitOrLandscape.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait">
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

And yes you can have multiple menu items. Just create multiple ApplicationBarMenuItem objects and add them all to the ApplicationBar.MenuItems collection, or define them in the XAML:

C#

```
private void BuildApplicationBar()
{
    ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
    ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Minimized;

    ApplicationBarMenuItem menuItem1 = new ApplicationBarMenuItem();
    menuItem1.Text = "menu item 1";
    menuItem1.Click += menuItem1_Click;

    ApplicationBarMenuItem menuItem2 = new ApplicationBarMenuItem();
    menuItem2.Text = "menu item 2";
    menuItem2.Click += menuItem2_Click;

    ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(menuItem1);
    ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(menuItem2);
}
```

XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="menuButton1" Text="menu button 1"
                                          Click="menuButton1_Click" IsEnabled="True"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="menuButton2" Text="menu button 2"
                                          Click="menuButton2_Click" IsEnabled="True"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Comment: ok I'll check this out. In regard to the device orientation and number of menu items, I was wondering how it is best to determine the resulting height of the app bar when showing the menu items, since this will adjust according to the number of menu items in the appbar. When subscribing to the StateChanged event, how would I move the `ImageBar` ListBox according to the exact speed and height of the opened and closed appbar?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to check the size of the app bar. So you might just need to do some trial and error to get it to look good. You definitely won't be able to match the speed of the appbar moving up/down, you'll only be able to snap to it once it's done moving and the event fires.